# If number have inside number string

Tags: php, mysql

i want to find stable number if have inside long number in database with php.

For example:

```
Stable number: 150

Number list: 1568940, 545198650, 15580
```

Can i find number of inside that number list.

Like this:

```
   (1)(5)6894(0) = 150 have that 150 string
   545(1)986(5)(0) = 150 have that 150 string 
   (1)(5)58(0) = 150 have that 150 string
```

is it possible?

Comment: I don't follow, how are you getting those number from the first pairings? or the db has `(1)(5)6894(0)` and you just want values inside `()`?

Comment: You could check if a string contains 1, 5, 0. And if it does that means it contains 150.

Comment: Write out the process by hand first, then turn that into code.

Comment: @LeonKunštek `501, 510, 105, 015, 051` all pass your test and fail OP's requirements.

Comment: @Sammitch I know, but it's a starting point from which you can build up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could perform a regular expression search on those strings, however doing so in a database with a large data set may prove rather costly.

```
$subjects = ["1568940","545198650", "15580", "5551000", "015", "1805"];

foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    if (preg_match("/(1)\d*(5)\d*(0)\d*/", $subject, $match) && count($match) == 4) {
        echo "$subject contains string 150\n";
    } else {
        echo "$subject does not contain string 150\n";
    }
}
```

This should give you the following output...

> 1568940 contains string 150
>
> 545198650 contains string 150
>
> 15580 contains string 150
>
> 5551000 does not contain string 150
>
> 015 does not contain string 150
>
> 1805 does not contain string 150

In MySQL...

```
SELECT fieldname FROM table WHERE fieldname REGEXP "(1)*(5)*(0)*";
```

It might help if you explained in more detail how you're getting this data and why it is you need to identify if it contains these characters.

Comment: Ok, here's OP's next homework question, because it will be valuable to you too: Now instead of checking for `150` we want to check for any arbitrary string of numbers. Points will be deducted for continuing to use regular expressions.